# What's the need memcached with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, memcached

I am developing a simple login system, and I'll have to store two cookies. One indicating which user is logged, and other indicating the "plan" (database) that the user belongs. Well, at client side the first cookie (us_auth) and the second (pl_auth), will store hashes (md5) to make a key that I can check on server side.

Now at the server side I'll store these two keys to assign to them values to route the user correctly. A simple authentication system.

Well, here the question comes. At PHP we have $_SESSION, and at Node we have modules that make the same thing, but I want something that I have more control, to work directly with the data. I have two choices:
Memcached, or a simple global var that store an object with key->value (in my case, hash->value).

What's the best choice in my case? At simple point of view, the second alternative seems to be more fast, pratical and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple global variable will fail if you replicate your application. Variables are not shared between processes (or even machines).

If you don’t plan on replicating your app, just restart your process, the memory allocated to that process will be lost, so will your in-memory session variables.

A memcached server can help you with that.

This is not specific to nodejs. You’ll have the same problem with PHP or any other technology.